# Show list of all names from JSON in C#

Tags: c#, json

I'm pretty new to C#, and maybe this is pretty simple to fix, but I've been reading over it for alot of hours now, and I can't seem to figure out how to make it work.

I want to retrieve a JSON-file from a url and show all the "names" from the file in a complete list.

The Json I'm trying to get the names from looks like this:

```
[{
  "endpoint":"127.0.0.1",
  "id":2,
  "identifiers":"steam:1",
  "license:1",
  "xbl:2533274989967058",
  "live:1","discord:1"],
  "name":"Name1",
  "ping":7
 },
 {
  "endpoint":"127.0.0.1",
  "id":3,
  "identifiers":"steam:2",
  "license:2",
  "discord:2",
  "fivem:2"],
  "name":"Name2",
  "ping":26
 },
 {
  "endpoint":"127.0.0.1",
  "id":5,
  "identifiers":["steam:3","license:3","discord:3"],
  "name":"Name3",
  "ping":34
 }
]
```

My RootObject (Gotten from http://json2csharp.com/):

```cs
public class RootObject
{
    public string endpoint { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public List<string> identifiers { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int ping { get; set; }
}
```

And the code itself:

```cs
WebClient client1 = new WebClient();
string strPageCode = client1.DownloadString("http://127.0.0.1:30120/players.json");
List<RootObject> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(strPageCode);
try
{
    MessageBox.Show(string.Join("\n", list), "Playerlist");
}
catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("No players online","Playerlist");
}
```

I tried alot of different methods so, and so far I've gotten it to show the amount of names, but it shows up like this: [Image](https://i.imgur.com/ddwFLrY.png)

I described it as good as possible, english is not my native language, so please tell me if it doesn't make sense and I'll try to rephrase it.

Comment: You need to override `ToString()` in order to get it to show something other than what the default implementation offers.

Comment: Probably a copy error -- your json is malformed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually trying to display an object which has low sense (an object that has many properties)

You can either use a loop and build a string using something like :

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var obj in list)
{
    sb.AppendLine(obj.name);
}
MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString(), "Playerlist");
```

**Or** override the `ToString()` method to your class and let your code as is :

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string endpoint { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public List<string> identifiers { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int ping { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ooh, I see now, and got it to work with the examples you gave! - Thanks you alot, appreciate it :)

Comment: I got it to work with overriding the ToString(), thanks. - How would I go about posting it to TextBox, if you know that? - Currently I have tried `textBox1.Lines = string.Join("\n", list);` and `textBox1.Lines = (string.Join("\n", list));` which gives me this error: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'string[]'`

Comment: @PatrickSørensen, you are trying to assign a string (names concatenated  with new lines)  to an array of string. You can try:  `textBox1.Lines = list.Select(item=>item.name).ToArray()`. The `Select` method comes from `System.Linq namespace`.